# Insert an image every x item in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items and need to render an image between every 10 items.
Items should be rendered in a 2d grid, the image should appear in a new line.

it should be something like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I could list the items using map, I thought to check the index if it is divided by 10, we can add the image, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution I think you can use:

```
<div id="container" style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
{arrayList.map((listItem, index) => {
  const cardinalIndex = index + 1;
  const item = !(cardinalIndex % 10) ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div id="item" style={{flex: '1 1 25%'}}>
        {listItem}
      </div>
      <img style={{flex: '1 1 100%'}} src="" />
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : (
    <div id="item" style={{flex: '1 1 25%'}}>
      {listItem}
    </div>
  );
  return item;
})}
```

Comment: @NadaGhanem Had the same idea, but I'm wondering how your code is different from mine

Comment: it is quite similar. Now, the image appears as an item, I wonder how to put it in a new line!

Comment: Outside the #container div ?

Comment: it should be inside but in a new line(like the image above), I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: There is a couple problem with this code. 1. You render image instead of item and no between. 2. Item is the parameter of the map function and also redefined inside.

Comment: I believe this is accomplished using flexbox,  don’t know how you are handling the CSS

Comment: The above code replaces each 10th item by the image, which is not right, the item should be there!.

Comment: Yep! thank you @Peter I fixed it, also Nada the example also shows how to use flexbox in order to accomplish the layout on your picture

Comment: This code is wrong, it replaces each 10th item intsead of inserting a new one, please check out my solution, it's working and i provided you an example

Comment: I changed it in order to not replace the item with the image, it append it... @h-des your answer is not written with JSX syntax or using ES5 React functions

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks a lot!. First time to know about React fragment!.

Comment: He did not provided any code, so i just gave him an simple algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
//itemList is your array

let temp = [];

while (itemList.length > 0) {
  temp.push(itemList.splice(0, 10));
}

let res = [];
temp.forEach(e => {
  res = [...res, ...e, 'new item here'];
});

//res is your output array with inserted elements
```

And here's working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tkr1d8vg/

Comment: Thanks, @h-des, I will test it with react, maybe there is an easier way to do it!